# Create a query that shows all dates within a date range

Tags: ms-access-2010, date-range

Here's my question.
I have a table (tblCourses) that has three columns: Course, StartDate, and EndDate

I want to create a query that gives me all the dates that are between StartDate and EndDate.

So if I have

- Course: A
- StartTime: 1/10/15
- EndTime: 1/15/15

I want the query to show:

Course; NewDate

- A   _ 1/10/15
- A   _ 1/11/15
- A   _ 1/12/15
- A   _ 1/13/15
- A   _ 1/14/15
- A   _ 1/15/15

I've done a lot of google searching, and I've looked through stackoverlow forums, but I can't seem to find a solution.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As Yermo states in his answer, one approach would be to use a [Dates] table that contains every valid date covering a period of time. Another approach would be to use a [Numbers] table containing integer values from zero to (some sufficiently large number), e.g.,

```
 n
--
 1
 2
 3
...
19
20
```

Once that table has been created you could use a query like

```sql
SELECT tblCourses.Course, DateAdd("d", Numbers.n, tblCourses.StartDate) AS NewDate
FROM tblCourses, Numbers
WHERE DateAdd("d", Numbers.n, tblCourses.StartDate) <= tblCourses.EndDate
```

which would return

```
Course  NewDate   
------  ----------
A       2015-01-10
A       2015-01-11
A       2015-01-12
A       2015-01-13
A       2015-01-14
A       2015-01-15
```

Comment: @ConservationSpecialistNS You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28033157/edit) with additional information, including the details of your latest attempt, and see if you get better answers.

Comment: Ok, my grammar isn't usually that bad.  :(
So let's try this again...
I tried your sql code using a table that already has a bunch of dates, and it works!  The only weird thing is that the whole date range won't show up; the StartDate and the date afterwords won't appear in the query.  (i.e., my query will show everything in the example you provided above, but not 2015-01-10 or 2015-01-11.)   
    
However, this seemed to solve the problem:     DateAdd("d",DateYearID-2, StartDate)

Thank you sooo much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually better solved in code than in the SQL query.

The reason it's not straight forward is you are trying to generate rows in a result set that are not in the table.

As a quick hack you could create another of dates and fill it to cover a few years. Then you could do a straight join which would get you the result you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying that.  Not sure how to do the join, but I'll play with it and see what happens.  Thank you!!